# How to do offline transfer using NSDL? for unlisted stocks

Tags: india, nse-india, bse-india

CDSL provides easi/easiest based offline transfer facility.
Whereas how to do this in case of NSDL online?
Also how to do interdepository transfer from NSDL

Thanks